# How can I make matrix of two column in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, matplotlib

Hi I am trying to plot the two values in matrix form, I tried many things but nothing worked, can someone please help? I want similarity values to be the values, my data:
https://github.com/mayuripandey/Data-Analysis/blob/main/matrix.csv

Desired output:[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use `pivot_table`:

```
df['Topic_model'] = df['Topic_model'].str.split('-', n=1).str[1].astype(int)
out = (df.pivot_table('Similarity', 'Topic_model', 'Topic_model')
         .rename_axis(index='Topic_2', columns='Topic_1'))
```

Output:

```
>>> out
Topic_1   -1    0         1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9         10        11    12   13   14   15        16   17        18        19        20        21        22   23   24   25        26        27        28   29   30   31   32   33
Topic_2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
-1       0.25  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
 0        NaN  1.0       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
 1        NaN  NaN  0.111111       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
 2        NaN  NaN       NaN  0.111111       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
 3        NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN  0.111111       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
 4        NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.111111       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
 5        NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.111111       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
 6        NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.111111       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
 7        NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.166667       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
 8        NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.111111       NaN       NaN       NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
 9        NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.111111       NaN       NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
 10       NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.111111       NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
 11       NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.111111   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
 12       NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.25  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
 13       NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   NaN  0.0  NaN  NaN       NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
 14       NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   NaN  NaN  0.0  NaN       NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
 15       NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  0.0       NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
 16       NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  0.111111  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
 17       NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN  0.0       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
 18       NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN  NaN  0.111111       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
 19       NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN  NaN       NaN  0.111111       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
 20       NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN  0.111111       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
 21       NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.111111       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
 22       NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.111111  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
 23       NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.0  NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
 24       NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN  0.0  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
 25       NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  0.0       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
 26       NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  0.111111       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
 27       NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN  0.111111       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
 28       NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN  0.111111  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
 29       NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
 30       NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN  0.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
 31       NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  0.0  NaN  NaN
 32       NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  0.0  NaN
 33       NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mayuripandey/Data-Analysis/main/matrix.csv', usecols=['Topic_model', 'Similarity'])
df.Topic_model = df.Topic_model.apply(lambda x: x[0:6] + '0' + x[6:] if len(x) == 7 else x)
df = df.pivot(columns='Topic_model')
```

Output:

```
            Similarity                                                                                 ...
Topic_model   Topic--1 Topic-00  Topic-01  Topic-02  Topic-03  Topic-04  Topic-05  Topic-06  Topic-07  ... Topic-25  Topic-26  Topic-27  Topic-28 Topic-29 Topic-30 Topic-31 Topic-32 Topic-33
0                 0.25      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  ...      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
1                  NaN      1.0       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  ...      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
2                  NaN      NaN  0.111111       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  ...      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
3                  NaN      NaN       NaN  0.111111       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  ...      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
4                  NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN  0.111111       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  ...      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
5                  NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.111111       NaN       NaN       NaN  ...      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
6                  NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.111111       NaN       NaN  ...      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
7                  NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.111111       NaN  ...      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
8                  NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.166667  ...      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
9                  NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  ...      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
10                 NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  ...      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
11                 NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  ...      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
12                 NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  ...      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
13                 NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  ...      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
14                 NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  ...      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
15                 NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  ...      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
16                 NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  ...      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
17                 NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  ...      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
18                 NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  ...      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
19                 NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  ...      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
20                 NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  ...      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
21                 NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  ...      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
22                 NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  ...      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
23                 NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  ...      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
24                 NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  ...      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
25                 NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  ...      0.0       NaN       NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
26                 NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  ...      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
27                 NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  ...      NaN  0.111111       NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
28                 NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  ...      NaN       NaN  0.111111       NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
29                 NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  ...      NaN       NaN       NaN  0.111111      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
30                 NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  ...      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN      0.0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
31                 NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  ...      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN      NaN      0.0      NaN      NaN      NaN
32                 NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  ...      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN      0.0      NaN      NaN
33                 NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  ...      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      0.0      NaN
34                 NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  ...      NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      0.0
```